# Colors of cobaltodihistidine

Tags: blood, colors

I have heard the complex, *Cobaltodihistidine*, (not coboglobin) mentioned several times on this site in relation to alternative oxygen carriers, and I believe that this complex could be what my species uses.

There is only one problem, what color is it?

I have found a ton of information on the colors of other complexes but not this one, oxygenated or deoxygenated.

Comment: This isn't really a worldbuilding question, just a chemistry question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR - colorless or pale pink deoxygenated, amber when oxygenated

Robert J. Bassett and Jerome S. Schultz, "[Nonequilibrium facilitated diffusion of oxygen through membranes of aqueous cobaltodihistidine](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/32719/0000086.pdf?sequence=1)", in *Biochim. Biophys. Acta*, 211 (1970), pp. 194-215 (at PDF page 3).

> The presence of oxygen in a water solution of cobaltodihistidine produces a visible color change in the solution. An anaerobic solution if sufficiently dilute is practically colorless; if more concentrated, it is slightly pink; but when oxygenated, the solution color becomes deep amber. The color change may be reversed by flushing the solution with nitrogen or hydrogen and the cycle may be repeated essentially indefinitely